# Legends in CartoDB - Appearing in Map Editor but not in Shared Maps

Tags: carto

I have created a couple of maps in CartoDB and while the legends display when I am editting the map - they will not display when I share the maps.

Why this might happen and what I can do to fix it?

It is happening across all of my maps.

Comment: Hey there, we're fixing this bug. The fix will be deployed asap.

Comment: It's been fixed!

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug that has been already fixed by the team. All should be working as expected now.

Comment: I'm facing the same and in the editor too, I have premium membership with cartodb, please advice